# Can you share a Firestore Document with a link (ie dynamic link)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore DB where documents have users with roles. Only the owner and participants can view/edit the document.

I want to send a link (over email, messages, chat, etc.) that someone can click, it will take them in the app and ask to join the document.

**If I send a firebase dynamic link, is it safe to send the Firestore DocumentID in the url?** If not, what's a proper way of sending the DocumentID or a reference to it?

I am open to not using Firebase Dynamic Links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your Security Rules configured to only allow the correct signed-in user(s) to read/write that document AND the document Id doesn't contain date (e.g, it's a random ID and not for example an email address) AND knowing that Id cannot be used to make other correlations.

If you are concerned about any of the above, you could create a simple lookup collection in the form of:

Collection: `/lookup_links`
Document Id: `<Auto Id>`
Fields:

```
     document_id: <Real Document Id>,
     allowed_users: [<User Auth Id>, ...]
```

Make sure Security Rules validates the user ID is is in the array above, and send the auto id for this lookup collection to the user instead. Your app can then perform the read from here to get the real id over our secure DB connection.

The benefit of this method is you can revoke access at anytime by deleting the lookup document and not worry about the document ID still being listed in someones email account or being intercepted (some email still goes in plantext over networks).

Comment: Since I don't know if the user receiving the link has an account yet, my security rules rely on both user roles OR a one time random key. Basically, the first person who clicks the link can join the document, after that, no more.